# React-Bootstrap Popover on non-react element - wrong position and invariant error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12161/) illustrates the problem.

I'm trying to use the [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/) library to show a Popover on an existing page built without React.  The fiddle has an example of a vanilla Bootstrap popover and one created with react-bootstrap.

There are three errors:

- The popup is not positioned correctly on the element, it's at the top of the body
- In the `<textarea>` element React outputs `<noscript data-reactid=".0"></noscript>`
- In the console it throws the error ``` Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``. ```

I'm sure I'm doing something incorrectly, I just don't know what it is.

```js
var Portal = ReactBootstrap.Portal;
var Popover = ReactBootstrap.Popover;

// Create the popup dynamically and show it with bootstrap
var $username = $('#username');
var showBootstrapPopover = function() {
    $username.popover({            
        placement: 'top',
        title: 'Vanilla Bootstrap Popover',
        content: 'I am a vanilla Bootstrap Popover'
    }).popover('show');
}

var MyPopover = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Portal container={document.body} 
              placement="bottom" 
              target={() => document.querySelector(this.props.target)} 
              show={true}>
        <Popover title="React Popover">
          <div>I should be on the bottom of the textarea</div>
        </Popover>
      </Portal>
    );
  }
});

var reactUsername = React.render(<MyPopover target="#username" show={true} />, document.querySelector('#username'));

showBootstrapPopover();
reactUsername.setState({ show: true });
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="username" rows="1" cols="60" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs during picking DOM Node of children of `<MyPopover />`, because in the line

```
var reactUsername = React.render(<MyPopover .../>, 
                                 document.querySelector('#username'));
```

the `<MyPopover />` is mounted **into** `<textarea#username>`, which is incorrect as it actually sets the `render()` result of `<MyPopover />`
as the text of the `textarea` node...After that React can not find the expected DOM node, `<noscript></noscript>` here, and have to complain that *the DOM was unexpectedly mutated*. You could mount to another mountable DOM Node to get rid of this error.

Furthermore, `<Portal>` only put your `<Popover>` into `document.body`, to position the `<Popover>` right below the textarea, try `<Position>` or `<Overlay>`. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12170/)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much @okm! That makes a lot more sense now.